# Image Segmentation - Comparing GrabCut Method vs. Level Set Method

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

Checking the literature about image segmentation, if I am not wrong, there are two main approaches:

- Variational approach e.g. level-set optimization in Chan-Vese
- Combinatorial approach e.g. using graph cut in GrabCut

Can someone give me some high-level comparison between these two directions?

For example, I feel with level-set optimization one can easily  incorporate image structure (e.g. edges) into the energy function, which is not easy in Grabcut. Am I correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Level set is for continuous segmentation, multiphase. But Graph cut is for discrete segmentation, only two phase